# Fetching Core Data related Entities properties

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have two many-to-many related Entities, `Customer` and `City` and NSManagedObject subclasses generated from them. I have relationship from `Customer` to `City` called `cities`. In `City` there is a property called `city`. Now I am trying to fetch everything from entity `Customer` with simple `fetchResultsController`:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {

  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
  {
      return _fetchedResultsController;
  }
  self.managedObjectContext = [[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                 managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                            cacheName:nil];
  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

  return _fetchedResultsController; 
}
```

As a result I am retrieving everything fine except `cities` property ((null) value) with predicate

```
@"cities.name CONTAINS[cd] %@"
```

In `Customer` subclass I can use method:

```
-(City *)city 
{
  return (CDCities *)[[PTDataFetchHelper sharedInstance] entityForName:@"City"
                                                          withServerID:self.city_server_id
                                                             inContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 
}
```

and I am retrieving `city`-values fine, but this way slows down UI (displaying this data in tableView).
So, questions:

- if I perform basic fetch like this, am I retrieve values of specified entity only, or values from related entities too?
- If I need additional predicate, how can I modify it to fetch also `city` properties from `City` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetch request only fetches one entity type. If you fetch `Customer`, you get `Customer`s. But you can traverse Core Data relationships without doing additional fetch requests. Just ask any `Customer` instance for the value of its `cities` attribute. That will get you zero or more `City` instances, and you can ask each one of those for its `city` attribute.

I'm not sure what you're getting at with `@"cities.city [cd]"`. That's not a predicate. It could be part of a predicate, but it doesn't match the `city` attribute against anything. It's like one side of an equation.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sir! Sorry, I was tired, so wrote wrong predicate, my version of it - @"cities.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", question updated. But what exactly I should set in specifier if I want all name properties of all City-type objects?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. A predicate limits the results by allowing only instances that match the predicate. Since you say you want all of them, a predicate serves no purpose. If you want all city names, why not fetch `City` instead of `Customer`?

Comment: I want to fetch everything from `Customer` and value of `city` property in `City`.